# nginx error unable to bind to port 80: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)

Tags: centos, systemd, nginx

nginx is failing to start due to the following bind error:

```
Aug 15 21:01:46 user.mylabserver.com nginx[1488]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 
0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)
```

I am confused why this is happening because I am starting the service as root:

```
[root@labserver user]# systemctl start nginx
[root@labserver user]#
```

Additionally, it is an allowed port by SELinux:

```
[root@labserver user]# semanage port -l | grep http_port_t
http_port_t                    tcp      80, 81, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443, 9000
pegasus_http_port_t            tcp      5988
```

Nothing else is using port 80:

```
[root@labserver user]# netstat -nap | grep ':80'
[root@labserver user]#
```

My `nginx.conf` user setting:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
```

I do not want to change the user to root in `nginx.conf` as that would obviously cause some security concerns. With all that being said, I do not see any other reason why this is failing.

Comment: Is there a `user` setting in `nginx.conf`? Ports <1024 need to be opened by root.

Comment: You might want to add your `nginx.conf` file to the question as well.

Comment: @Deathgrip I have added it to the question.

Comment: Even with nginx running bound to port 80, `netstat -t | grep 80` will not show it. Try `netstat -nap | grep ':80'` or `lsof -nP -i :80 | grep LISTEN` to check for applications.

Comment: What version of CentOS? Shouldn't the pid file be `/var/run/nginx.pid`? On CentOS 6.x, by default there isn't a `/run` directory.

Comment: @Deathgrip, `[root@lab /]# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)`. Also, nothing is using port 80: `[root@lab /]# netstat -nap | grep ':80'
[root@lab /]#`. I see a `/run` directory as well.

Comment: How was Nginx installed. Was it compiled from source or maybe from the EPEL repository? Please include your **entire** nginx.conf file.